# Selenium unable to send keys as Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Tags: java, selenium

For the text type WebElement that I am trying to click and do a send keys using WebDriver, I am getting an "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with". I went through similar posts here in stackoverflow but the solutions posted there did not work for me.

I tried the javascript method as below without any success as I got nullpointer exception

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(map.getLocator("timesheet.intime"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].checked=true;", el);
```

I use the object repository method to get the locator.

```
//timesheet.intime=xpath://input[contains(@id,'txtSignIn')]
```

The HTML

```
<input id="gvTimesheetDay1_ctl02_txtSignIn" class="form-control input-sm" type="text"
    onblur="FormatCheck(event,this)" onkeydown="isBackSpace (event, this)"
    onkeyup="this.value = minmaxHH(this.value, 0, 23)" onkeypress="javascript:return
    isNumber (event)" onfocus="if(this.value=='HH:MM') this.value='';" placeholder="HH:MM"
    maxlength="5" name="gvTimesheetDay1$ctl02$txtSignIn">
```

I did some analysis on the WebElement: `.getSize()` returns 0 as height and width, `.isDisplayed()` returns false, `.isEnabled()` returns true. Please help me with a path forward as I am out of ideas.

Comment: The webelement properties are:
<input id="gvTimesheetDay1_ctl02_txtSignIn" class="form-control input-sm" type="text" onblur="FormatCheck(event,this)" onkeydown="isBackSpace (event, this)" onkeyup="this.value = minmaxHH(this.value, 0, 23)" onkeypress="javascript:return isNumber (event)" onfocus="if(this.value=='HH:MM') this.value='';" placeholder="HH:MM" maxlength="5" name="gvTimesheetDay1$ctl02$txtSignIn">

Comment: can you share the url here ?

Comment: Sorry, the URL and is not accessible over the web as it is corporate URL and would need access

Comment: Have you tried looking up the element in the browser console? Are you sure you have the right one? Is it actually visible at the point in the script when you are trying to access it? In your locator, you are only looking for a partial match for "txtSignIn".. are you sure this is the only element that matches that condition? If you execute `$x("//input[contains(@id,'txtSignIn')]")` in the browser, what does it return?

Comment: Thanks Jeff for responding. I was not being attentive as there were 7 matches for the same xpath String. I am basically trying to automate timesheet app with text fields to enter 'inTime' and 'outTime' for each day. Seven days of the week are show in separate sections and each section displays the 'inTime' and 'outTime' text fields only when I hit a '>' button that expands the section for the day and shows text fields. Using the firebug I saw that the text field which I needed for a particular day was highlighted correctly but missed to notice that there were seven other hidden matches

Comment: [input#gvTimesheetDay0_ctl02_txtSignIn.form-control.input-sm.ddlwidth property value = "" attribute value = "null", input#gvTimesheetDay1_ctl02_txtSignIn.form-control.input-sm property value = "" attribute value = "null", +--input#gvTimesheetDay2_ctl02_txtSignIn.form-control.input-sm property value = "" attribute value = "null", input#gvTimesheetDay3_ctl02_txtSignIn.form-control.input-sm property value = "" attribute value = "null", input#gvTimesheetDay4_ctl02_txtSignIn.form-control.input-sm property value = "" attribute value = "null" is the response- $x("//input[contains(@id,'txtSignIn')]")